# Switch Statement returning me null when using array

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to have a function which will return an array, however "b" variable returns always null but I expect to return an URL like variable "a".
Print a works perfect

Why is "b" not working and returning "null"?

```
def BuildURL(Source, Destination, CopyToEverywhere) {
    def FROM_URL
    def TO_URL
  
    switch(Destination) {
        case (CopyToEverywhere && Destination.startsWith("DPDHLPA"|"reference")):
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-something.com", "https://${Destination}-url.com"]
            break;
        case Destination.contains("author"):
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-something.com"]
            break;
        case Destination.contains("publish"):
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-url.com"]
            break;
    }

    switch(Source) {
        case Source.contains("author"):
            FROM_URL = "https://${Source}-something.com"
            break;
        case Source.contains("publish"):
            FROM_URL = "https://${Source}--url.com"
            break;
        default:
            FROM_URL = "https://${Source}-something.com"
            break;
    }
    print FROM_URL
    print TO_URL
    return [FROM_URL, TO_URL]
}
    
def CopyToBothInstances = false
(a, b) = BuildURL('source-author', 'dest-publish', CopyToBothInstances )
print a
print b
```

Comment: You should avoid using capital letters as the first letter of variables and methods

Answer (score 0):

You can't do switch statements like that...  The reason it was null is that none of them matched (and you don't have a default: for it)

http://grails.asia/groovy-switch-statement-examples

This works I think

```
def BuildURL(Source, Destination, CopyToEverywhere) {
    def FROM_URL
    def TO_URL
  
    switch(Destination) {
        case { CopyToEverywhere && (it.startsWith("DPDHLPA") || it.startsWith("reference") ) }:
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-something.com", "https://${Destination}-url.com"]
            break;
        case { it.contains("author") }:
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-something.com"]
            break;
        case { it.contains("publish") }:
            TO_URL = ["https://${Destination}-url.com"]
            break;
    }

    switch(Source) {
        case { it.contains("publish") }:
            FROM_URL = "https://${Source}--url.com"
            break;
        default:
            FROM_URL = "https://${Source}-something.com"
            break;
    }
    println FROM_URL
    println TO_URL
    [FROM_URL, TO_URL]
}
```

Using Closures as the `case` checks

Comment: I think if you delete the `case { it.contains("author") }:` case under `switch(Source)`, the behavior would be the same.  Is that right?

Comment: You're right Jeff   Updating the answer